# Google Charts API: Histogram, how to fuse bars and change x-ticks to integers

Tags: charts, google-visualization, histogram

I am using Google Chart API to create a histogram and want to modify bars to fuse with the ones next to them and change the xticks to integers.

**Question:**

How can I do the following:

- Fuse the bars with the one next to them?
- Make the h/x-ticks appear as `int`s?

**Current Output:**

[image]

**Ideal Output:**

[image]

**Relevant Research:**

I couldn't find all that much, apart from these two which helped with some of my problems but not the two above:

- [How does one go about creating an Histogram using the google chart api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827485/how-does-one-go-about-creating-an-histogram-using-the-google-chart-api)
- [GOOGLE: Home > Products > Charts > Guides > Histogram](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/histogram#example)

**MWE:**

```js
google.charts.load("current", {packages: ["corechart"]});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
     ['MyData', 'Value'],
     ['Val', 25.4],
     ['Val', 25.4], 
     ['Val', 25.4],
     ['Val', 25.4], 
     ['Val', 25.6],
     ['Val', 25.8],    
     ['Val', 25.8]
     ]);
  var options = {
   title: 'Stats',
   legend: {position: 'none'}, 
   width: 1100,
   height: 500,
   chartArea: {width: 900, height: 150},
   colors: ['#ff0000'],
   histogram: {bucketSize: 0.2, minValue: 22, maxValue: 28, hideBucketItems: true},
   // bar: { width: 5},
   // bar: {groupWidth: 0 },
   vAxis: {
      title: 'Frequency',
      titleTextStyle: {bold: false, italic: false},
      gridlines: {color: "white"},
      ticks: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
      }, //END V-AXIS
   hAxis: { 
      title: 'Values', 
      titleTextStyle: {bold: false, italic: false},
      type: 'category', 
      ticks: [22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28], // THIS IS NOT WORKING?!!!?
      }  //END H-AXIS
  }; //END OPTIONS

  var chart = new google.visualization.Histogram(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to get `hAxis.ticks` to work,
remove the option `hAxis.category`
(not sure what this does, didn't see it in the reference)

in order to remove the gap between the bars,
had to use the following option.

```
bar: {
  gap: 0
},
```

AND use frozen version `'45.2'` (or lower) of google charts...

```
google.charts.load('45.2', {...
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('45.2', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['MyData', 'Value'],
    ['Val', 25.4],
    ['Val', 25.4], 
    ['Val', 25.4],
    ['Val', 25.4], 
    ['Val', 25.6],
    ['Val', 25.8],    
    ['Val', 25.8]
  ]);
  var options = {
    title: 'Stats',
    legend: {position: 'none'},
    width: 1100,
    height: 500,
    chartArea: {width: 900, height: 150},
    colors: ['#ff0000'],
    histogram: {bucketSize: 0.2, minValue: 22, maxValue: 28, hideBucketItems: true},
    bar: {
      gap: 0
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Frequency',
      titleTextStyle: {bold: false, italic: false},
      gridlines: {color: "white"},
      ticks: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
    }, //END V-AXIS
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Values',
      titleTextStyle: {bold: false, italic: false},
      //type: 'category',
      ticks: [22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28]
    }  //END H-AXIS
  }; //END OPTIONS

  var chart = new google.visualization.Histogram(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: wow, thanks! But how did you know to use frozen version `45.2`?

Comment: I've had problems in the past with the `'current'` version, so when something doesn't work, I try other versions. you can see them all in the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)